# Alternative version of monotone convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a
>   sequence of positive measurable functions s.t.  $$ f_1(x)\ge f_2(x)
>  \ge \ldots \ge f_n(x)\ge ... \ge 0, \qquad \forall x\in X $$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in X$. If $f_1 \in
> L^1(X)$ then  $$ \lim_n \int_X f_n d\mu = \int_X f d\mu. $$

I think this is quite immediate from dominated convergence theorem. Indeed, every $f_n$ is dominated, i.e. $\vert f_n(x) \vert =f_n(x)\le f_1(x)$, for every $x \in X$. Since $f_1 \in L^1$, we have $\int_X f_n d\mu \to \int_X fd\mu$.

Is this correct?

Indeed, I have another proof of this fact: let's define $g_n(x)=f_1(x)-f_n(x)\ge 0$, $g_n(x)\le g_{n+1}(x)$ and $g_n(x)\to f_1(x)-f(x)$, for every $x \in X$. 
Then by monotone convergence, we get 
$$
\lim_n \int_X g_n(x) d\mu = \int_X f_1(x)-f(x)d\mu
$$
hence (since $f_1 \in L^1$, i.e. $\int_X f_1 d\mu < \infty$) we get - by subtraction - 
$$
\lim_n \int_X f_n(x) d\mu = \int_X f(x)d\mu
$$

Are both proofs correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see where $f_1$ is assumed integrable (and we need this, otherwise in the real line with Lebesgue measure, taking $f_n=\chi_{(n,+\infty)}$).

Comment: Sorry Davide, there was a typo in the text of the problem. Look at it now. I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both proofs are correct. I personally prefer the second one, as it involves only monotone convergence, hence it's a little less advanced.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.